# Reading a 32 bit integer from BYTE array. VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have created a BYTE array containing a image pixel data. Image is grayscale and each pixel intensity is a 32bit integer. Now I want to read the each pixel intensity( 32 bit int) and then do some operations on each pixel intensity and store back the modified pixel intensity (again in 32bit int). So my question is how can I read a 32 bit (or also 16 bit) integer from a BYTE array. (working in VC++/MFC).

Thank you.

Comment: do you know the endianness of the array?

Comment: How did you create the BYTE array without knowing how to do this?

Comment: Created- `BYTE inBuffer[size];' and then 'file.Read (inBuffer, sizeof (inBuffer));'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `memcpy` to get the data from your array of `BYTE` to an array of `int32_t` (or `uint32_t`).

If you don't need portability, your architecture probably allows casting the address of the first `BYTE` to a `int32_t*` and using it in-place.

If all your data always comes from a file, and nothing needs to work on the individual bytes, you could just read it directly into an array of `int32_t`.